# Using Youtube IFrame Player API within iOS app and compliance with Apple Guidelines

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, youtube-api, appstore-approval

We are building an iOS app and part of its functionality is to play specific youtube content.

I've done some research regarding direct embedding youtube videos in iOS apps and basically it comes down to two alternatives:

1. Parse the youtube html and retrieve the video stream direct URL. Then play the downloaded stream in iOS's native player. This is fine by Apple guidelines, but it breaches the Youtube's ToS which clearly indicate that all embedding should be done using Player APIs. Lots of posts here point to a couple of cocoa libraries which do exactly this.
2. Use Youtube's IFrame API within a UIWebView. Naturally, this doesn't breach Youtube's ToS. But as far as I can tell, it breaches Apple's guidelines which indicate that all HQ files larger than a couple of MBs need to be streamed using HTTP Live Streaming (HLS). Youtube doesn't support HLS streams via its APIs.

So, my question is how do other apps on the App Store (like Jasmine for iPad for instance) embed Youtube content without breaching Apple' guidelines and Youtube's ToS?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I know several apps people have built that just break that restriction and are still on the app store.